# How to find python lib directory?

Tags: python, makefile, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement the DeepMimic paper but am stuck at the setup. Ho wdo I change the last part of the Makefile: python lib directory?

Modify the Makefile in DeepMimicCore/ by specifying the following,

```
EIGEN_DIR: Eigen include directory
BULLET_INC_DIR: Bullet source directory
PYTHON_INC: python include directory
PYTHON_LIB: python lib directory
```

https://github.com/xbpeng/DeepMimic

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Well, are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: no I am usind a conda env

Comment: Simply edit the Makefile and provide the directories on your system. First install libeigen3-dev, libpython2.7-dev libbullet-dev. The directories are the include dirs and lib directories